# How to create a MorphologicalGraph from MorphologicalBranchPoints

Tags: graphs-and-networks, image-processing

I want to select the morphological branch points of a thinned image to create a `MorphologicalGraph` like the one obtained by `Pruning`.

[image]
[image]

I want to avoid the pruning step. How can I delete from the `MorphologicalGraph` of the first image all points that are *not* morphological branch points?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBeKs.png"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
mg = MorphologicalGraph[img, ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
vdF = With[{gr = #}, VertexDelete[gr, _?(VertexDegree[gr, #] <= 1 &)]] &;

Row[NestList[vdF, mg, 4]]
```

[image]